# Checking list values

Tags: python

I have a list that must only contain ints, how would i proceed to control every element of the list and return a message if it is not an int?

Could i for instance somehow use isdigit()?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what "number" means in this context? Do they all have to be `int`s? How about `float`s?

Comment: Why don't you know ahead of time? What else might be in the list? What's a "number" in this context? In Python, we don't check like this--we know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`all`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) and the abstract base class [`Number`](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number):

```
>>> all(isinstance(x, Number) for x in mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use abstract base class [numbers](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html) and a simple loop:

```
from numbers import Number

for item in my_list:
    if not isinstance(item, Number):
        print '{} is not a number'.format(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) in such case?

From docs:

> Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is constrained.

Comment: Using `array` for typing (instead of a memory optimization) seems wrong. Plus, this assumes OP has control over how the list is controlled and wants to throw an error the second a non-int item is added.

Comment: @delnan: Why it seems wrong? I'm relatively new to Python. Asking seriously. If python can guarantee something I need for me then why implement it instead of using standard library? I know Arrays are mostly used for performance, but does it mean that it is the only reason to use it? Regards.

Comment: Checking for and enforcing (specific) types is very much discouraged due to the dynamic nature and the preference of duck typing (look it up NOW if you don't know what that means). There are numerous reasons for why, mostly related the extensibility. In this case, it's highly unlikely that an occurrence of a `decimal.Decimal` is unacceptable, but using an `array` would break it - and that's just one example.

Comment: @delnan: I know what duck typing is. In this case user wanted list of ONLY numbers. Using structure which give us flexibility to put there anything and then manually forcing that each element is a number instead of using structure which stores only numbers is kind of strange.

Comment: @Michael: An `array` requires a specific kind of number (say, float). A list with an `isinstance(elem, Number)` check accepts any number. See the connection to duck typing?

Comment: @delnan: I see what you mean. Thanks for constructive comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if all elements of a list are of a particular type:

```
all(map(lambda x: type(x) == type(0), list))
```

This will return False iif there is at least one element of `list` which is not of the same type as 0. You can change the condition to fit your needs, depending on whether you need integers or reals or anything else.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use _type(0)_ instead of simply _int_ i.e. _type(x) == int_?

Comment: Using type function for identity is discouraged. Use isinstance if necessary.

Comment: Well, the whole answer is rather poor, actually;)